# Python generator vs callback function

Tags: python, profiling, generator

I have a class that solves an exact cover problem using a recursive, backtracking algorithm. Originally, I implemented the class with a callback function I passed to the object during initialization. This callback is invoked whenever a solution is found. In looking at someone else's implementation of the same problem, I saw that they were using yield statements to pass a solution out, in other words, their code was a python generator. I thought this was an interesting idea so I made a new version of my class to use yields. I then ran comparison tests between the two versions and, to my surprise, I found the generator version ran 5 times slower than the callback version. Note that, except for switching in a yield for a callback, the code is identical.

What is going on here? I'm speculating that, because a generator needs to save state information before yielding and then restore that state when restarting at the next call, it is this save/restore that is what makes the generator version run so much slower. If this is the case, how much state information is the generator having to save and restore?

Any ideas from the python experts?

--Edited 7:40 PDT

Here is the solver code which uses yield. Replace the first yield below with a call to the callback function and change the following loop with the second yield to just a recursive call to solve for the original version of this code.

```
   def solve(self):
      for tp in self.pieces:
         if self.inuse[tp.name]: continue

         self.inuse[tp.name] = True
         while tp.next_orientation() is not None:
            if tp.insert_piece():
               self.n_trials += 1
               self.pieces_in += 1
               self.free_cells -= tp.size

               if self.pieces_in == len(self.pieces) or self.free_cells == 0:
                  self.solutions += 1
                  self.haveSolution = True
                  yield True
                  self.haveSolution = False
               else:
                  self.table.next_base_square()
                  for tf in self.solve():
                     yield tf

               tp.remove_piece()
               self.pieces_in -= 1
               self.table.set_base_square(tp.base_square)
               self.free_cells += tp.size

         self.inuse[tp.name] = False
         tp.reset_orientation()
```

The mail loop which invokes the solver (after initialization, of course) is

```
   start_time = time.time()
   for tf in s.solve():
      printit(s)

   end_time = time.time()
   delta_time = end_time - start_time
```

In the callback version, the loop is gone with just a single call to solve.

Comment: Please include a (simplified, but complete) example and how you measured the time.

Comment: `yield`ing from a recursive function sounds like it requires extra `for` loops to pass the results down to the caller, doesnt it? Maybe you mean a coroutine, passing results with `send` ?

Comment: How many solutions are typically found? (Are you yielding a lot or relatively infrequently?)

Comment: For the record, two tiny tests of mine (http://www.ideone.com/7XCro, http://www.ideone.com/VuKRn, http://www.ideone.com/DhTJF) seem to indicate that there's performance little difference between yield and a callback with the callback improving slowly while it does more work. I'm eager to see OP's counterexample.

Comment: I added the relevant code for the generator version of my code. I also show how the main invokes the solver and how I did my timing.Regarding, FogleBirds question, both version find exactly the same set of solutions which, for the given problem is correct.

Comment: Well, I still can't reproduce. I wrote a [heavily recursive version](http://www.ideone.com/xeZVM) of the previous benchmarks, but the callback/generator performance is quite different. I suggest you use `timeit` (it's not as fragile, as it runs many times and takes some countermeasures against other programs taking the majority of CPU time). Perhaps [profiling by line](http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/) also helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What i meant in my comment, ("yielding from a recursive function sounds like it requires extra for loops to pass the results down to the caller") is this line:

```
          for tf in self.solve():
             yield tf
```

These lines recursively loop over the results from the deeper recursion stages. That means that a single result is iterated over on each level of the recursion, resulting in *a lot* of unnecessary looping.

Let me illustrate with this example:

```
n = 0
def rekurse(z):
    global n
    if z:
        yield z
        for x in rekurse(z-1):
            n += 1
            yield x

print list(rekurse(10))
print n
```

As you can see this simply counts down from 10, so you'd expect a a linear number of iterations. What you can see though is that `n` grows quadratically - `recurse(10)` loops over 9 items, `recurse(9)` over 8 items and so on.

The more items you have, the more time Python spends on these simple lines. Callbacks completely avoid that problem, so I'd suspect that is the problem with your code.

A optimized implementation of [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) could fix this (see [this paragraph](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#optimisations)). In the meantime I don't think it's a good idea to yield from recursive functions (at least if they recurse deeply), they just don't work well together.

Comment: Nevermind, you are correct. See http://www.ideone.com/ylAg2 (clone and adjust N to see the growth) +1 for enlightening us.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying here, Jochen. However, if I remove the loop and replace it with just the recursive call to solve, it no longer works. Is that something you would expect to happen? In other words, in order to make the generator version work, the loop is required but, because the loop is there, it is very inefficient relative to the callback version of code.

Comment: @delnan: Nice, thanks for the profiling :-) @sizzzzlerz: Yeah, there is nothing *wrong* with your code, you need that for loop in order to use yield in a recursive function. Recursive functions and yield just don't work well together and you'd be better of with the callbacks or writing the function without recursion.

Comment: I've done some measurements in python 3.8 and the generator version seems to take a bit longer (~3s for 1M elements) than the callback one: https://gist.github.com/SimonLammer/f8e653ff15724c97a42e96db28171132