# Python generator with recursive call

Tags: python, recursion, generator

I am trying to yield nodes in a tree with a generator using a preorder depth first search. The parents node can have any number of children and the children are stored in a list.

I figured this code would work, but it appears that the for loop is iterating over each child without actually going into the recursive call.

```
def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t.label, t.val
    for child in t.children:
        traverse_tree(child)
```

Does anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the function, for each call, the `yield` expression only gets hit once.  So your generator will only yield one thing.  To get it to yield more than one thing, you need to yield from the children too:

```
def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t.label, t.val
    for child in t.children:
        yield from traverse_tree(child)
```

This is python 3.3+ syntax (IIRC).  For earlier versions:

```
def traverse_tree(t):
    yield t.label, t.val
    for child in t.children:
        for label, val in traverse_tree(child):
            yield label, val
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer [Recursion using yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8991840/recursion-using-yield), and more specifically the `yield from` construction here: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-380.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function that contains `yield`, the code in the body of the function does not run. Instead, it returns a generator object.

You can use a list to store the result instead:

```
def traverse_tree(t, list):
    list.append((t.label, t.val))
    for child in t.children:
        traverse_tree(child, list)
```