# python performance- function vs generator functions

Tags: python, performance

I want to know which one is better in performance terms: a "regular" python function with state, or a generator. Unlike [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704220/python-generator-vs-callback-function), I'm using the most simplified function to isolate the problem:

Regular function:

```
 >>> def counter_reg():
         if not hasattr(count_regular,"c"):
             count_regular.c = -1
         count_regular.c +=1
         return count_regular.c
```

Generator functions:

```
>>> def counter_gen():
    c = 0
    while True:
        yield c
        c += 1

>>> counter = counter_gen()
>>> counter = counter.next
```

In both cases, calling `counter()` and `counter_reg()` will produce the same output.

Which one is better in terms of performance?
Thanks,

Comment: Just by looking at the first function, I would not recommend doing that. At least define a class with `__iter__`, or if you need it as a function have a default argument `def counter_reg(c=[-1])` and mutate that

Comment: `counter_gen()` produces a new counter every time you call it, `counter_reg()` increments a global (albeit namespaced to the function). Big difference.

Comment: And you can time these things yourself with the `timeit` module.

Comment: Better optimize for readability. I doubt generator performance is the bottleneck. (If it is, you probably should not be using Python.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can benchmark Python functions using the [timeit module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html):

**test.py:**

```
import itertools as IT

def count_regular():
     if not hasattr(count_regular,"c"):
         count_regular.c = -1
     count_regular.c +=1
     return count_regular.c

def counter_gen():
    c = 0
    while True:
        yield c
        c += 1

def using_count_regular(N):
    return [count_regular() for i in range(N)]

def using_counter_gen(N):
    counter = counter_gen()
    return [next(counter) for i in range(N)]    

def using_itertools(N):
    count = IT.count()
    return [next(count) for i in range(N)]
```

---

Run python like this to time the functions:

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test as t' 't.using_count_regular(1000)'
1000 loops, best of 3: 336 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test as t' 't.using_counter_gen(1000)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 172 usec per loop
% python -mtimeit -s'import test as t' 't.using_itertools(1000)'
10000 loops, best of 3: 105 usec per loop
```

For a more thorough benchmarking, try different values of `N`, though in this case I don't think it is going to matter.

So as you would expect, using `itertools.count` is faster than either `count_regular` or `counter_gen`.